# How can I add a log entry to watchdog every time form_set_error() is triggered on user_account_form_validate()?

Tags: hooks, forms

I'm not much of a coder so I'm having a real hard time figuring this out.

I have a custom module and I'm trying to override `user_account_form_validate()` (from user.module) so that I can add a watchdog entry every time a specific instance of `form_set_error()` is called:

```
elseif ((bool) db_select('users')->fields('users', array('uid'))->condition('uid', $account->uid, '<>')->condition('name', db_like($form_state['values']['name']), 'LIKE')->range(0, 1)->execute()->fetchField()) {
  form_set_error('name', t('The name %name is already taken.', array('%name' => $form_state['values']['name'])));
}
```

I need to do this because sometimes the [Email registration](http://drupal.org/project/email_registration) module causes this error to fire and I want to make sure that this doesn't occur; so, to ensure users aren't seeing this error, I want to log it in watchdog if it occurs.

I know I can hack core and add the following line just after form_set_error:

```
watchdog('mymodule', 'Registration error: %name was already registered.', array('%name' => $form_state['values']['name']), WATCHDOG_ALERT);
```

But how I can I do this without hacking core?  I tried various permutations of function

> function mytheme_user_register_form_validate (&$form, &$form_state) {}

in a custom module but I couldn't successfully get Drupal to use my function instead of the core one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a new validation handler to a form, you need to implement `hook_form_alter()`. In your case, I would use the following code, which adds an extra validation handler that is executed before the other ones added by the User module.

```
function mymodule_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  array_unshift($form['#validate'], 'mymodule_user_register_validate');
}

function mymodule_user_register_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  $account = $form['#user'];

  if (isset($form_state['values']['name'])) {
    if ($error = user_validate_name($form_state['values']['name'])) {
      // This is intentionally empty.
    }
    elseif ((bool) db_select('users')->fields('users', array('uid'))->condition('uid', $account->uid, '<>')->condition('name', db_like($form_state['values']['name']), 'LIKE')->range(0, 1)->execute()->fetchField()) {
      // Log the error with watchdog().
    }
  }
}
```